# How can I publish a project that uses .net 4.7.2 with --no-restore

Tags: .net, azure-devops, msbuild

I have a sdk style project that targets .net 4.7.2

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

There is just a single class in it and it does not have dependencies.

I can build and publish the project in Visual Studio.

I now use the following build pipeline

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: 'DotnetApp.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'DotnetApp.sln'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: 'DotnetApp.sln'
    arguments: ' --arch x64 --no-restore -f net472 '
```

This results in the error

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net472/win-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net472' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.

I realy need to use  --no-restore in the publish step. Without it the publish step works.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you specify that your project has to be published runtime-specific with the `--arch x64` argument but no preparation has previously been made to ensure the required assets for this operation are in place.

You have two options:

1. Specify `RuntimeIdentifiers` (plural):

As the error message says:

> You may also need to include 'win-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.

you can add this expected runtime identifier to your project file so the `restore`task will make sure the required assets are in place:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

2. remove the `--arch x64` from your publish arguments. As long as you don't have x64-specific code (e.g. native dependencies or manually implemented interop calls that require 64 bit) *and* can possibly execute in an 32bit-only environment, this can be omitted.